# Simple App that contains only three Buttons: plus Button, minus Button, and reset Button

Tags: android, button, layout

I am creating a simple Android App that contains only three Buttons: plus Button, minus Button, and reset Button.
but unfortunately my App crashes when i pressed one of the three buttons.

following is my main Activity Code:

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    public class Main extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

        Button btnAdd, btnMinus,  btnReset;
        TextView tvCounter;
        int count = 0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            btnAdd = (Button)findViewById(R.id.addButton);
            btnMinus = (Button)findViewById(R.id.minusButton);
            btnReset = (Button)findViewById(R.id.resetButton);

            btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnMinus.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnReset.setOnClickListener(this);

            tvCounter = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.counterTextView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.addButton:{
                count++;
                tvCounter.setText(count);   
            }

                break;
            case R.id.minusButton:{
                count--;
                tvCounter.setText(count);
            }
                break;
            case R.id.resetButton:{
                count = 0;
                tvCounter.setText(count);       
            }
                break;
            default:

                break;
            }

        }


    }
```

This is my Layout file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/tasbih"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/counterTextView"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:textSize="50sp"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="0"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addButton"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="+" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/resetButton"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/addButton"
        android:text="Reset" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/minusButton"
        style="@style/buttonStyle"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/addButton"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/addButton"
        android:text="-" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

please suggest me towards right. I am beginner

Log-cat:

```
08-21 20:44:45.693: D/ActivityThread(20653): handleBindApplication:com.example.subhanallah
08-21 20:44:45.723: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20653): getCSCPackageItemText()
08-21 20:44:45.723: D/DisplayManager(20653): DisplayManager()
08-21 20:44:45.803: D/OpenGLRenderer(20653): Enabling debug mode 0
08-21 20:44:45.833: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(20653): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
08-21 20:44:45.843: I/Timeline(20653): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41ea3d50 time:18178662
08-21 20:44:46.764: I/Timeline(20653): Timeline: Activity_launch_request id:com.example.subhanallah time:18179580
08-21 20:44:46.784: W/ApplicationPackageManager(20653): getCSCPackageItemText()
08-21 20:44:46.944: I/Timeline(20653): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41f688a0 time:18179769
08-21 20:45:06.213: I/Timeline(20653): Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41f688a0 time:18199034
08-21 20:45:07.885: W/ResourceType(20653): No package identifier when getting value for resource number 0x00000001
08-21 20:45:07.885: D/AndroidRuntime(20653): Shutting down VM
08-21 20:45:07.885: W/dalvikvm(20653): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41702bc0)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): Process: com.example.subhanallah, PID: 20653
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:1404)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4262)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.example.subhanallah.Main.onClick(Main.java:39)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4496)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18603)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5433)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1268)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1084)
08-21 20:45:07.895: E/AndroidRuntime(20653):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: open the logcat and paste the errorlog here

Comment: Also, probably best to tell us which  button is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you intentionally setting the TEXT of `tvCounter` to the integer, `count`? You should be setting the text to a string value:  `tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));` unless you intend on setting the text via string resource ID.

The `setText` function may accept an int value which references a string resource(see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(int)).  The string resource is likely not found by the given `int` you provide(`count`)

Also on another note about your switch-case statement: it is not advised(ant not allowed) to use a switch-case with non-constants on the case when using build tools revision14+). See this page for more details:  http://tools.android.com/recent/buildchangesinrevision14

> Warning: Generating IDs as non final in the library projects, means that the library code cannot treat these IDs as constants. This means, for example, that you can’t use res IDs in a switch statement.

In the code you provided, you're checking for button ID (`R.id.minusButton`, etc).  You should change your switch/case to something more like this:

```
if(v.getId() == R.id.addButton) {
    count++;
    tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
else if(v.getId() == R.id.minusButton) {
    count--;
    tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
else if(v.getId() == R.id.resetButton) {
    count = 0;
    tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Comment: Now I want to Add the facility in my App as that of repeating some sound after the interval of 10 to 15 minutes, all the day. 
@binnyb Do you know Something about this?

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like an ID was not located in one of your views.  maybe instead of the that case statement just do something like this.

```
if (butnAdd == v) {
} else if (btnMinus == v) {
} else if (btnReset == v) {
} else {
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your whole onClick method with this code:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.addButton:
            count++;
            break;
        case R.id.minusButton:
            count--;
            break;
        case R.id.resetButton:
            count = 0;
            break;
    }
    tvCounter.setText(String.valueOf(count));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is mistake of Type Casting, you are setting the data of integer type to text type.